# Find all numbers $n$ such that $S_5, S_7$ contains an element of order $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Could you tell me if my answer is correct? Have I missed out something?

---

> **Problem** Find all numbers $n$ such that $S_5$ contains an element of order $n$.

**Solution** Any element in $S_5$ falls in one of the categories:

- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c,d,e)$. The order for this is $5$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c,d)$. The order for this is $4$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c)$. The order for this is $3$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b)$. The order for this is $2$.
- Identity. The order is $1$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c)(d,e)$. The order for this is $6$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b)(c,d)$. The order for this is $2$.

Hence, the possible orders are $1,2,3,4,5,6$.

---

> **Problem** Find all numbers $n$ such that $S_7$ contains an element of order $n$.

**Solution** Any element in $S_7$ falls in one of the categories:

- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)$. The order for this is $7$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$. The order for this is $6$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c,d,e)$. The order for this is $5$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c,d)$. The order for this is $4$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c)$. The order for this is $3$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b)$. The order for this is $2$.
- Identity. The order is $1$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c,d,e)(f,g)$. The order for this is $10$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c,d)(f,g)$. The order for this is $4$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c)(d,e)$. The order for this is $6$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b)(c,d)$. The order for this is $2$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c,d)(e,f,g)$. The order for this is $12$.
- It is an element of the form $(a,b,c)(e,f,g)$. The order for this is $3$.

Hence, the possible orders are $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,12$.

---

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes the order of the elements for the two groups are correct.
Check also:
http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S7
http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_symmetric_group:S5

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the website and your answer.